# Angular 5: Is it possible to link a local npm module?

Tags: npm, package, angular5, local

I have a custom node module, that I **can't publish on NPM**.

I'd like to use it as any module I have on NPM.

Is it possible without the awful thing of copying the folder into the node_modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: **YES, IT's POSSIBLE**.

Let's assume your module has a dist folder, with the built source
(for example I run gulp on my *src* folder and procude the *dist* folder).

you simply got to run `npm pack ./dist` in your library.

> this will produce a **tgz** archive with your library named your-library-version

then you can install your module in your project by simply running

`npm i path-to/your-library-version.tgz`

And you're done.

Let's say my library fodler is `C:\ngx-mat-lib`

so my tgz will be in this folder, since the *dist* folder should be a child of *ngx-mat-lib*.

In my project I'll run

`npm i C:/ngx-mat-lib/ngx-mat-lib-0.0.1.tgz`

> Note: using forward slashes to avoid doubling them